# Get key value from object using dynamic expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create an arrow function to do this
`const acess = (data,item)=> Object.values(data.item)[0]`
But the second argument item will not be recognized after `data.` argument.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

script.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'item')

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `data[item]` is what you're looking for

Comment: What are you passing to your function? Per the error message you posted, `data` is undefined.

Comment: Note that there are *two* problems here.  One is the notation you're using, which the answer below has addressed.  (And for which there are multiple duplicates.)  The other is the error you're asking about, which is telling you that `data` is `undefined`.  What value do you expect `data` to have and why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Bracket Notation instead of Dot Notation.

Reason:

> Dot Notation only allows static keys while Bracket Notation accepts
> dynamic keys. Static key here means that the key is typed directly,
> while Dynamic key here means that the key is evaluated from an
> expression.
>
> Via - [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/dot-notation-vs-square-brackets-javascript/)

So

```
const acess = (data,item)=> Object.values(data.item)[0]
```

Should be:

```
const acess = (data,item)=> Object.values(data[item])[0]
```

Example snippet:

```js
const acess = (data,item)=> console.log(Object.values(data[item]));
const x = {type:"car", model:"x1000", color:"black"};
acess(x, 'model');
```